# Map=geemap.Map() won´t execute

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

I'm trying to create a map using Sentinel 2 data with Jupyter notebook. Every time I try to run Map=geemap.Map() it takes a lot of time to execute. My notebook just shows me [*]. I literally left it running ovrnight and it didn't even finish. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Litteraly this doesn't even run:

```
import geemap as ge
Map=ge.Map()
```